# Is it possible to have a same collection instance in a dictionary associated with multiple keys in swift?

Tags: swift, collections

I have a `Set` instance and want to put it into a `Dictionary`, and associate it with multiple keys so I can lookup/modify it in the future.

Following Python code is what I want to achieve in Swift.

```
s = set()
D = {}
D["a"] = s
D["b"] = s

D["a"].add("Hello")
D["a"].add("World")
print(D["b"]) # getting {"Hello", "World"} back
```

I tried something like following in Swift.

```
var s = Set<String>()
var D = Dictionary<String, Set<String>>()
D["a"] = s // copy of s is assigned
D["b"] = s // another copy of s is assigned

D["a"]!.insert("Hello")
D["a"]!.insert("World")
print(D["b"]!) // empty :(
```

Since collections in Swift hold value semantics, by the time I put a set into a dictionary, new instance is created. Is there any workaround? I know I could use `NSMutableSet` instead of Swift's `Set`, but I want to know how I can approach this by using collections with value semantics if possible.

Comment: What you're asking for is *explicitly* reference semantics (like in Python), and is the opposite of value semantics. What aspect of value semantics did you want? ("Value semantics" literally means "what you've asked for here never happens.")

Comment: It seems like you are using the word `Collection` all over your question as a synonym for `Set`, which is clearly wrong. `Collection` is a protocol in Swift, which can be adopted by classes as well as structs. So I assume your question is actually specifically about `Set` and not about collections in general.

Comment: The workaround you ask for you already included, use an NSMutableSet.  Value semantics literally means not allowed to do what you are asking to do.

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't even a "workaround." This is just using a reference type for the case where you want reference semantics. Just like "use a Double" is the answer for "I want an number that can be an integer, but can also have values between integers."

Comment: @Rob I want to use reference semantics with Swift but I don't want to link Foundation framework to my program.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Sorry for my misuse of these terms. But it doesn't have to be `Set`. Other collections do the same behavior. (ex Array, Dictionary)

Comment: @Popmedic but I don't want to link Foundation framework...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah! Now we get to the heart of it. You just want a reference type based on stdlib rather than using the one that Foundation gives you. That's straightforward to implement, if slightly tedious. Just wrap a Set in a class. If you don't want full `SetAlgebra` or `Collection` conformance, you don't have to implement all of these methods. (And you might want some more `init` methods to make this more convenient, but hopefully those implementations are fairly obvious from your code needs.)

```
final class RefSet<Element> where Element: Hashable {
    private var storage: Set<Element> = Set()
    init() {}
}

extension RefSet: Equatable where Element: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: RefSet<Element>, rhs: RefSet<Element>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.storage == rhs.storage
    }
}

extension RefSet: SetAlgebra {
    var isEmpty: Bool { return storage.isEmpty }

    func contains(_ member: Element) -> Bool {
        return storage.contains(member)
    }

    func union(_ other: RefSet<Element>) -> RefSet<Element> {
        return RefSet(storage.union(other.storage))
    }

    func intersection(_ other: RefSet<Element>) -> RefSet<Element> {
        return RefSet(storage.intersection(other.storage))
    }

    func symmetricDifference(_ other: RefSet<Element>) -> RefSet<Element> {
        return RefSet(storage.symmetricDifference(other.storage))
    }

    @discardableResult
    func insert(_ newMember: Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element) {
        return storage.insert(newMember)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func remove(_ member: Element) -> Element? {
        return storage.remove(member)
    }

    @discardableResult
    func update(with newMember: Element) -> Element? {
        return storage.update(with: newMember)
    }

    func formUnion(_ other: RefSet<Element>) {
        storage.formUnion(other.storage)
    }

    func formIntersection(_ other: RefSet<Element>) {
        storage.formIntersection(other.storage)
    }

    func formSymmetricDifference(_ other: RefSet<Element>) {
        storage.formSymmetricDifference(other.storage)
    }
}

extension RefSet: Collection {
    typealias Index = Set<Element>.Index
    var startIndex: Index { return storage.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { return storage.endIndex }

    subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        return storage[position]
    }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        return storage.index(after: i)
    }
}
```